# how to Show underline in anchor if having href using css

Tags: css

i am trying to make a nav bar when user hover on it **underline is shown with some distance under it** 
Here what i achieve but can't successfully make distance between underline and link please see my desire output as images

```css
body {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.underline-on-hover:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<span class="underline-on-hover">Shop</span>
```

But my desire result should look like this 
[image: Desire result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use border instead and control the distance with padding :

```css
body {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  
}

.underline-on-hover:hover {
  padding-bottom:20px;
  border-bottom:3px solid;
}
```

```html
<span class="underline-on-hover">Shop</span>
```

Or a better solution is to use pseudo-element and you will be able to control distance and length :

```css
body {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  
}
.underline-on-hover {
 position:relative;
}

.underline-on-hover:hover::after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  bottom:-10px; /* control position */
  height:2px; /* control height */
  width:30px; /* control lenght */
  background:#000;
}
```

```html
<span class="underline-on-hover">Shop</span>
```

Comment: Thanks brother really help full Thanks again 
Please also up vote my question

Answer (score 3):

You can use `border-bottom` to style the underline of the `:hover`:

```css
body {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
.underline-on-hover:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom:2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<span class="underline-on-hover">Shop</span>
```

You can adjust the space between text and underline with `padding-bottom`:

```css
body {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
.underline-on-hover:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom:2px solid black;
  padding-bottom:10px;
}
```

```html
<span class="underline-on-hover">Shop</span>
```

To adjust the space under the menu item you can use `margin-bottom`.

Comment: Brother
Make sense But 
i am trying to make a nav bar when user hover on it underline is shown with some distance under it

Answer (score 1):

You could instead just use border bottom with padding for distance

```css
body {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
.underline-on-hover:hover {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<span class="underline-on-hover">Shop</span>
```